# Alternative to TextViewCreated such as (TextViewChanged)?

Tags: c#, textview, vsx

I am creating a small Visual Studio 2010 extension in C# which uses the IWpfTextViewCreationListener and TextViewCreated to capture when a new TextView is opened in the VS environment. The problem I am having is that this method only fires when a new window is opened via the VS Solution Explorer window, and not fired when VS already contains opened windows when started, and switching window tabs. I have tried looking for something like TextViewChanged, but could not find such method. Is there anyway to capture the new TextView when another tabbed window is selected?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question has also been posted on the MSDN VS Extensibility forum:
[VSX 2010 - Alternative to TextViewCreated such as (TextViewChanged)?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/44bd0197-3370-4f6b-b943-570ec093b25a)

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no TextViewCreated, but if you register to IWpfTextView.GotAggregateFocus as it is created, you get a hook to every switch between files:

```
    public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
    {
        textView.GotAggregateFocus += TextViewCameToFocus;
        // Do stuff when a new IWpfTextView is created...
    }

    void TextViewCameToFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var focusedTextView = (IWpfTextView)sender;

        // Do stuff when a specific IWpfTextView comes to focus...
    }
```

You may also want to keep track of the IWpfTextView objects, if you want to be able to link between the fired events to your logic of each textview.